Magento 2.4.5-p5 - Need to display out of stock products at last on category page
I am using Magento 2.4.5-p5, Out-of-stock products should be displayed at the bottom of category page.
I also tried sorting the products. I set the sort order for products in the category within the admin panel, but after saving, it displays in an older (random) order.
Could you please help me figure out how to fix this?

You can use a plugin in order to put all out of stocks products at the end.
Create a new module first :
etc/module.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogSearch"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>

registration.php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_Module', __DIR__);

And add the plugin :
etc/di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
        <plugin name="Vendor_Module_Plugin_Magento_Catalog_Model_Layer" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer" sortOrder="1000"/>
    </type>
</config>

app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Magento/Catalog/Model/Layer.php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Model;


/**
 * Class Layer
 */
class Layer
{

    /**
     * Sort items that are not salable last
     * prepareProductCollection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    public function beforePrepareProductCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
    )
    {

        $collection->getSelect()->order('is_salable DESC');
        $orderBys = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        array_unshift($orderBys, array_pop($orderBys));
        $collection->getSelect()->setPart(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER, $orderBys);

        return [$collection];
    }

}

Execute the following command in the console :
magento module:enable Vendor_Module

Then flush cache and compile if necessary.

It should work by default using position sorting. If you still encounter issues, please try the solution provided below.
Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $subject
     * @param bool $printQuery
     * @param bool $logQuery
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeLoad(\Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $subject, 
    $printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
    {
        $orderBy = $subject->getSelect()->getPart(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $outOfStockOrderBy = array('is_salable DESC');
        $subject->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $subject->getSelect()->order($outOfStockOrderBy);

        return [$printQuery, $logQuery];
    }
}

Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection">
        <plugin name="Vendor_outofstock::OutofstockEnd" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar"/>
    </type>
</config>

Now run the below commands :
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento c:f


I tried but it doesn't work

I don't want toolbar sorting, it should be always show out-of-stock products at the bottom of the category page.
